# Magento CMS home page not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have a strange issue with some of my Magento stores.  The content from the home pages has disappeared.  The sites in question are:-

http://www.hornchurchfineart.co.uk/

http://www.artofwood.co.uk/

http://www.domingodirect.co.uk/

These pages were working fine before and suddenly stopped working, this problem also has my hosting company stumped too.

I have cleared my cache both in the admin and by manually deleting the files in the /var/cache folder but to no avail.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Many thanks in advance,

Garry

Comment: Your homepage is a cms or the index/index/index page ? Could you check the cms page or the index_index_index layout ?

Comment: The CMS page is correct. Also the config is set correctly.

Comment: Did you find out anything? Or did a re-install? :P

Comment: Still not working.  Am now writing my own mini-magento instead

Comment: i have same issue looking for solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
In my .htaccess file I had the following entry.

SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1

By commenting this out the front pages returned.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there isn't a product with a blank URL rewrite.

You can check this by going to **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management** and sort the column **Request Path**. If there is an item in there with a blank Request Path (it should be at the top after sorting), it will override the homepage. Delete the rewrite to get your homepage back.

This can happen if you have used an import script (such as MagMi) to create products.

Answer (score 0):

On my site, the contents of the homepage are stored in the database. Maybe something caused your entry to get blanked out?

Open the Admin -> CMS -> Page for the one that is your homepage and then under the Design tab on the left, there is a section called "Layout Update XML". This is where the body of my "Home" page comes from. In this section is XML from the template we bought, inserting their "blocks" onto our homepage.

Our template is a paid one from Template Master and here's one section of our "Layout Update XML" that makes up part of my store's homepage:

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="easyslide/slider" name="homepage.slideridentificator">
        <action method="setSliderId"><id>default_a034</id></action>
  </block>
  <block type="core/template" name="tab_wrapper" template="cms/highlight.tab.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thanks for your answer.  I have checked my XML blocks and they are all correct.

Comment: If it is enabled, perhaps try disabling it and then re-enabling it. I have seen this behavior in other areas of Magento. There has got to be something "simple" that got changed which affects this. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error: the front end not being able to access the CMS homepage. In my case it was because I had renamed the home page from 'home' to 'homepage' in the backend: CMS> Pages> URL Key.